# validate dynamically created div depending on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code that allows a user to pick between 2 options of a person `TYPEA` and `TYPEB`.

```
SELECT PERSON - { TYPEA, TYPEB  }
```

Depending on the choice, it shows:

```
TYPEA - { TYPEA WITH ID, TYPEA WITHOUT ID }
TYPEB - { TYPEB WITH ID, TYPEB WITHOUT ID }
```

It is working with this:

#### html:

```
<div id="person-A-withID"    class="persons" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="person-A-withoutID" class="persons" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="person-B-withID"    class="persons" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="person-B-withoutID" class="persons" style="display:none"></div>
```

#### jQuery:

```
$(function () {
   $('#has_id').show();
   $('#select_person').change(function () {
     $('.persons').hide();
     if ($('#select_person').val() == 'typeA') {
        $("#has_id").html('');
        $("<option/>").val('0').text('--Choose Type A--').appendTo("#has_id");
        $("<option/>").val('person-A-withID').text('person-A-withID').appendTo("#has_id");
        $("<option/>").val('person-A-withoutID').text('person-A-withoutID').appendTo("#has_id");
     }

     if ($('#select_person').val() == 'typeB') {
        $("#has_id").html('');
        $("<option/>").val('0').text('--Choose Type B--').appendTo("#has_id");
        $("<option/>").val('person-B-withID').text('person-B-withID').appendTo("#has_id");
        $("<option/>").val('person-B-withoutID').text('person-B-withoutID').appendTo("#has_id");
     }
  });

  $('#has_id').change(function () {
    $('.persons').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

I have a function to validate if the value is empty or equals 0 with the following code:

```
function validate(id, msg) {
    //search object
    var obj = $('#' + id);

    if(obj.val() == '0' || obj.val() == ''){
            //append error to particular div called #id__field_box 
        $("#" + id + "_field_box .form-error").html(msg)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and I call it inside a validate function like this:

```
var validation = function(){
  var err = 0;
  err += validate('select_person', "select person.");

  //err += validate($('#select_person:first-child').attr('has_id'), "Select wether it has ID or not."); 
  //err += validate('has_id', "Select wether it has ID or not.");   

  if(err == 0){
         //continue
  }else{
         //stop
  }
};
```

Now, the problem is that I cannot validate the `has_id` part, I am only able to validate the first one. How can I use it to search for `has_id`?

[here is a fiddle, please take a look at it](http://jsfiddle.net/LEfbX/27/)

Comment: It appears that your fiddle doesn't have the `validate` function, and the `validation` function is never called.  How exactly are you calling these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, there isn't an element with the id of 'selector_persona'. This prevents your second validate function from working. By passing it the id of what you're trying to validate ('has_id'), it references the object and checks to make sure it has a value.

Choose a person, leave the second select as "--Choose Type A--" and click ok.  It returns your error.
http://jsfiddle.net/zyglobe/LEfbX/131/

```
var validation = function(){
    var err = 0;
    err += validate('select_person', "select person.");
    err += validate('has_id', "Select whether it has an ID or not.");           
    if(err == 0){
        alert('continue');
    } else{
        alert('error: ');
    }
};
```

You may also check this part:

```
$('#select_person:first-child').attr('has_id')
```

You're trying to find an attribute with the name has_id, which would work for something like this:

```
<select has_id="some_value" />
```

I think you mean to select the attr('id') which will return the value of 'has_id':

```
<select id="has_id" />
```